# Select one element from input array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there some easy option for selecting one element from input array? I hope it's clear. If not, ask for explanation:

In HTML there can be array of inputs with same name, i.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

OR

```
<input type="text" name="name[0]">
<input type="text" name="name[1]">
```

Is there jQuery selector for `name[1]`? Or do I have to assign some id/class to select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's an attribute selector:

```
var name1 = $('input:text[name="name[1]"]');
```